# Python While true, Try/Except, returning value

Tags: python, while-loop, return, global, try-except

When I try to return a value after making a variable and putting a while True, try/except commands, the variable doesn't return the value. I am trying to globalize this "starting" so that it can be used.

```
def start_time():
    while True:
        try:
            starting = int(input("Please enter a starting hour(HH): "))
            if starting < 0:
                print("There are no negative hours!")
            elif starting > 24:
                print("There are only 24 hours in a day!")
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter in a correct format (HH)")
    return starting
def end_time():
    while True:
        try:
            ending = int(input("Please enter an ending hour (HH): "))
            if ending < starting:
                print("You can only plan a day!")
            elif ending < 0:
                print("There are only 24 hours in a day!")
            elif ending > 24:
                print("There are only 24 hours in a day!")
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter in a correct format (HH)")
    return ending

#obtain starting and ending time
start_time()
end_time()

#confirm starting and ending time
```

Thanks

Comment: You never break out of the while loop when the input is correct. Replace `pass` with `break` (or just an early return there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, one amendment is needed to achieve your stated aim:

replace:

```
start_time()
```

with

```
starting = start_time()
```

when a function is called that returns a value without an explicit place for that value to be put python in effect throws away the value.

Comment: One other thing: you'll need to change the pass to a break on the else branch of your if statement or, more efficiently, put the return statement there or you'll never get out of the infinite loop!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `starting` global, return `starting` value to the caller. Use of global needs to be avoided if possible. Read why it is a bad design [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158418/9844252). To implement in better way, your caller should be modified as:

```
starting = start_time()
```

Now starting time is obtained in `starting`.

Similarly,

```
ending = end_time()
```

Ending time is obtained in `ending`.

Also `pass` does not break out of the infinite `while` loop. It does nothing, but is used when a statement is required syntactically but the program requires no action.  Use a `break` in-place of `pass`. It exits out of the innermost loop.

Read about the usage of `break` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).